# Dot product of two vectors obtained by cross product

Tags: vectors, cross-product

How can I prove the following identity:

$$(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\cdot(\vec{c}\times\vec{d}) = (\vec{c}\cdot\vec{a})(\vec{b}\cdot\vec{d})-(\vec{b}\cdot\vec{c})(\vec{a}\cdot\vec{d})$$

Comment: Could you not just let $a=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, and the same for $b$, $c$ and $d$, then just find the cross products, then take the dot product? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: If you don't want to use @Cataline's approach, you need to use previously-known identities using cross and dot products. Which ones do you know?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I think I can figure it out by using the fact that $\vec{a}\cdot(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})=\vec{b}\cdot (\vec{c}\times\vec{a})=\vec{c}\cdot(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})$ and also $\vec{a}\times(\vec{b}\times\vec{c})=\vec{b}(\vec{a}\times\vec{c})-\vec{c}(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})$. For some reason it didn't occur to me to use those. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have the following identities for vectors $\vec{x}$,$\vec{y}$,$\vec{z}$:

$$\vec{x}\cdot(\vec{y}\times\vec{z})=\vec{y}\cdot(\vec{z}\times\vec{x})=\vec{z}\cdot(\vec{x}\times\vec{y})$$

and

$$\vec{x}\times (\vec{y}\times\vec{z})=\vec{y}\;(\vec{x}\cdot \vec{z})-\vec{z}\;(\vec{x}\cdot \vec{y})$$

Let $\vec{a}\times\vec{b} = \vec{x}$:

$$(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})\cdot(\vec{c}\times\vec{d})=\vec{x}\cdot(\vec{c}\times\vec{d})$$

By using the first identity,

$$\vec{x}\cdot(\vec{c}\times\vec{d}) = \vec{c}\cdot(\vec{d}\times\vec{x})$$

Which can be expanded by using the second identity:

$$\vec{c}\cdot(\vec{d}\times(\vec{a}\times\vec{b}))=\vec{c}\cdot(\vec{a}\;(\vec{d}\cdot\vec{b})-\vec{b}\;(\vec{d}\cdot\vec{a}))$$

Giving us the desired identity

$$(\vec{c}\cdot\vec{a})(\vec{d}\cdot\vec{b})-(\vec{c}\cdot\vec{b})(\vec{d}\cdot\vec{a})$$

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure where the first identity comes from?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way of proving the identity using index notation, Einstein summation convention, and the Levi-Civita symbol's magic.

The $i$-th components of the cross products can be written as,

$$
(\vec{a} \times \vec{b})_i = \epsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k
$$

$$
(\vec{c} \times \vec{d})_i = \epsilon_{ipq}c_pd_q
$$

The dot product between these cross products is,
$$
\begin{align*}
(\vec{a} \times \vec{b})_i (\vec{c} \times \vec{d})_i &= \epsilon_{ijk}a_jb_k \epsilon_{ipq}c_pd_q \\
&= \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ipq} a_jb_k c_pd_q
\end{align*}
$$

By the properties of the Levi-Civita, we have that,

$$
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lpq} = \delta^{ijk}_{lpq}
$$

Contracting by setting $i = l$, we obtain the contracted epsilon identity,

$$
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ipq} = \delta^{j}_{p}\delta^{k}_{q} - \delta^{j}_{q}\delta^{k}_{p}
$$

Making use of this in our dot product,

$$
\begin{align*}
(\vec{a} \times \vec{b})_i (\vec{c} \times \vec{d})_i &= (\delta^{j}_{p}\delta^{k}_{q} - \delta^{j}_{q}\delta^{k}_{p}) a_jb_k c_pd_q \\
&= \delta^{j}_{p}\delta^{k}_{q} a_jb_k c_pd_q - \delta^{j}_{q}\delta^{k}_{p} a_jb_k c_pd_q
\end{align*}
$$

The Kronecker deltas force indices together and eliminate off-diagonals so,

$$
\delta^{j}_{p}\delta^{k}_{q} a_jb_k c_pd_q = \delta^{k}_{q} a_jb_k c_jd_q = a_jb_k c_jd_k
$$

$$
\delta^{j}_{q}\delta^{k}_{p} a_jb_k c_pd_q = \delta^{k}_{p} a_jb_k c_pd_j = a_jb_k c_kd_j
$$

Therefore our result becomes,

$$
\begin{align*}
(\vec{a} \times \vec{b})_i (\vec{c} \times \vec{d})_i &= a_jb_k c_jd_k - a_jb_k c_kd_j \\
&= a_jc_jb_kd_k - a_jd_jb_kc_k
\end{align*}
$$

By definition of the dot product, we see that the R.H.S contains products of dot products so writing everything in vector notation, we finally have,

$$
(\vec{a} \times \vec{b}) \cdot (\vec{c} \times \vec{d}) = (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{c})(\vec{b} \cdot \vec{d}) - (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{d})(\vec{b} \cdot \vec{c})
$$